# Git: How to manually manipulate/craft a merge between two branches when no conflict occurs

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Say there's a feature branch that we'll refer to as branch `A`.
Branch `A` contains three files, `A1` (index.html), `A2` (main.css), and `A3` (script.js).
From branch `A`, branch `B` was created/checked out, giving `B1`, `B2`, and `B3`.
Now, say that all contents of `B1` - `B3` where completely removed and totally different code was written then committed to branch `B`.
Say that the new code of all the files of branch `B` will ultimately need to be integrated into the original code as a subset of it.

I expected to be able to achieve this integration of `B` code into `A` code by checking out branch `A` and running `git merge B`. I assumed that this would present me with a merge conflict with which I could craft new versions of `A1` - `A3` to commit to branch `A`.
Git, however, did not produce the expected merge conflict and instead completely replaced all the `A` code with the `B` code.

How can the code of these two branches be integrated?
I realize one could copy code from the `B` files and past it into the code of the `A` files, all outside of Git. I consider that a less than ideal solution, though, because the project history won't, then, reflect the fact that some of `A` code came from `B`.

Comment: I have almost exactly the same (though less drastic) a problem. It is a shame no-one has answered this question because a solution would be really useful. Perhaps if I ask a question without branches that might illuminate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no new commit on branch `A` then branch `B` is a descendant of `A`. Therefore a merge is (per default) done as a fast forward, i.e. no explicit merge commit is generated only `A` is set to `B`. (You could generate an explicit merge commit with `git merge --no-ff` option.)

The idea of a merge is to integrate all the new changes to the old state. If the change is replacing the content of one file by something completely different, then integrating that change is done by doing exactly this on branch `A`, which will result in the new content.

I currently cannot think of a situation where this is not what you want.

Comment: Consider a file has text in it. You edit, save and commit. You then edit the original text (perhaps in a different copy of the editor), save and then commit. So now you have two commits with divergent edits from the same file. You want to merge them, but `git merge` assumes that the file history tells the whole story and refuses to let you do that in a sane way.

I do not see how to use `git merge --no-ff` to do what you suggest.